# How do I retrieve only the autoids since I last called a function from firebase using swift.

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My firebase database is structured as:

```
events
  autoid
    event name: "" 
    event date: "" 
  autoid
    event name: "" 
    event date: ""
```

I currently have a function that returns all of the autoids from the events node then writes them to an array so I can use them in another snapshot.

The first time the function runs, it works as expected. But if I leave the view and come back it crashes. Which I think is because it's trying to append the array again, duplicating the values.

Here's my function

```
func getEvents() {

        self.dispatchGroup.enter()
      Database.database().reference().child("Events").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
              //  self.dispatchGroup.enter()
                for child in dictionary {
                    let eventid = child.key
                    self.eventsArray.append(eventid)
                   // print(eventid)
                    //                    print(self.eventsArray)


                }
                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                print(self.eventsArray)

            }

        })
    }
```

Wondering how I can retrieve the existing autoids and any new ones that have been added when I return to the view. I tried .childadded but it returns event name, event date etc and I need the autoid.

I'm new to firebase and swift so any tips or recommendations are welcomed!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to first handle the initial data and then get notified of only the new data, you're typically looking for the `.childAdded` event.

```
Database.database().reference().child("Events").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    let eventid = snapshot.key
    print(eventid)
    self.eventsArray.append(eventid)
    self.dispatchGroup.leave()
    print(self.eventsArray)
}
```

When you first run this code, the `.childAdded` event fires for each existing child node. And after that, it fires whenever a new child is added. Similarly, you can listen for `.childChanged` and `.childRemoved` events to handle those.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I tried this initially and I keep getting the children of my autoid, not the autoid itself when i use childadded instead of value. Do I need create a new key/value pair beneath each autoid that includes the autoid to retrieve it? I’d. Event id >> autoid >> Event name: “”, Event date: “”, event is: Autoid.key

Comment: You'll indeed get triggered per child with my code. That's why I removed the loop you had for going over the children. But `let eventid = snapshot.key` should now give you the key of the event in my code. Doesn't it do that?

Comment: I don't know how in the world I missed it but I missed the for loop that was missing from your code. Thanks a bunch, that did the trick! So it was my for loop that was looping one level further down, that makes sense now.